# Passing complex type from partial view to controller action via form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, razor, partial-views, form-submit

So, I'm working on a new project using ASP.NET MVC. Honestly I don't have pretty much experience with it (or any web development) before so maybe its a simple question.

I have a partial view that's a search box that is shared between various of the web views. The view has a drop down list and a text box. I need that once the user post the form (using the search button) that values arrive to the index action of the search controller as a `SearchFilterModel` object.

Now, the form is calling the index action on the Search controller. That's working (see attached code). But the thing is, the id param (that must be a `SearchFilterModel`) of the index method doesn't arrive (it's null).

I don't know how to pass the object from the form to the controller. ¿What I'm doing wrong?

The thing is if I replace `new { id = search }` with `new { id = "something" }` (changing the type of the sent parameter, then an string arrives (it works) or if I write `new { id = 1 }` then an int arrives. I guess there's something related with the thing that `SearchFilterModel` isn't a native type but a complex one.

Any idea?

```
@using Hermes.Models.Helpers

@{
    var search = CacheHelper.Instance.SearchFilter;
    using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new { id = search  }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "No se creó la cuenta. Corrija los errores e inténtelo de nuevo.")
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Búsqueda por tipo de producto</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(s => search.SearchFilter)
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(s => search.SelectedSearchFilter, new SelectList(search.SearchFilter))
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    @Html.LabelFor(s => search.SearchQuery)
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(s => search.SearchQuery)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => search.SearchQuery)
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Search Controller's Index Action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SearchFilterModel id)
        {
            var x = CacheHelper.Instance.SearchFilter;

            ViewBag.Filter = id.SelectedSearchFilter;
            ViewBag.msg = String.Format("Se están buscando {0}, con el filtro {1}", id.SelectedSearchFilter, id.SearchQuery);
            ViewBag.ResultsCount = 0;

            return View();
        }
```

SearchFilterModel

```
public class SearchFilterModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "¿Qué características?")]
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text )]
    [Display(Name = "¿Qué buscar?")]
    public List<String> SearchFilter { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "¿Qué buscar?")]
    public string SelectedSearchFilter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: seems like you want to pass a SearchFilterModel object from partial view to the index contrller

Comment: @COLDTOLD That's what the title says :) ¿Any idea?

Comment: can you share the definition of SearchFilterModel class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the posted answers work so finally the solution was:

In the "Home" controller (its view renders the "Search" partial view) I declare a new instance of the `SearchViewModel`, pass it to the "Home" view (via `ViewBag`) recover it on the "Home" view and the pass it to the "Search" partial view via `Render` method:

```
SearchFilterModel searchFilter = ViewBag.SearchFilter;
@Html.Partial("SearchProduct", searchFilter)
```

Now, on the "Search" view, just declare the Begin form as usual and now it works perfectly. It seems (to me) that the problem is related with the lifetime of the object (on my question and my original attempt I was trying to declaring it just before the form and it seems to me that it isn't possible to do that). Now, it works great but I'm concern about the performance implications on doing it this way. Any suggest'll be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build a JSON whose syntax matches the class definition and then send this data across to your action and MVC should handle the conversion of the JSON to your class or you could use the `Deserialize` method of the the `JavaScriptSerializer` class and create the object as a string.

Thus bind an event handler to your submit function and then use some ajax api to send the data across. Here is an example using jquery:

```
var searchFilter=[];
for each( value in the dropdown)
   searchFilter.push(value);

var searchFilterModel={
SearchQuery: "value1", //get the data from the textbox
SelectedSearchFilter: "value2", //get the value from dom
SearchFilter: searchFilter
}

$.ajax(
{
url: url //your action method
data: {
SearchFilterModel:searchFilterModel
},
success:function(){} //callback function
})
```

Action signature remains the same.

and to use the JavaScriptSerializer method:

```
var searchFilter=[];
for each( value in the dropdown)
   searchFilter.push(value);

var searchFilterModel={
SearchQuery: "value1", //get the data from the textbox
SelectedSearchFilter: "value2", //get the value from dom
SearchFilter: searchFilter
}

$.ajax(
{
url: url //your action method
data: {
id1: searchFilterModel
},
success:function(){} //callback function
})

[HttpPost]   
public ActionResult Index(string id1)
{
var id=new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<SearchFilterModel>(id1);
var x = CacheHelper.Instance.SearchFilter;
ViewBag.Filter = id.SelectedSearchFilter;
ViewBag.msg = String.Format("Se están buscando {0}, con el filtro {1}", id.SelectedSearchFilter, id.SearchQuery);
ViewBag.ResultsCount = 0;
return View();
}
```

Let me know if this works out for you..

Comment: I was wondering, is this the only way to work this. My question goes 'cause I'm trying and It results that If I set the SearchFilterModel as the Model of the partial view (not another object) then it works without setting even as a param on the form declaration. Or, given that is the "model" the framework built this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

When posting complex object with forms, it's important that the attribute "name" matches with the objects property.

By using the `@Html.TextBoxFor(s => search.SearchQuery)`  mvc will create the necessary attributes for you.

And you should replace the form tag since the form contains the necessary information to create the object `using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post))`